# How do I remove the 'double border' on the inside walls of this table? CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the follwing HTML and CSS:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row one, cell one</td>
            <td>Row one, cell two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row two, cell one</td>
            <td>Row two, cell two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row three, cell one</td>
            <td>Row four, cell two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row three, cell one</td>
            <td>Row four, cell two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row three, cell one</td>
            <td>Row four, cell two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row three, cell one</td>
            <td>Row four, cell two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row three, cell one</td>
            <td>Row four, cell two</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0.6em;
}
tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0.6em 0;
}
tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0.6em 0 0 0;
}
tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0.6em 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daft/LwT7k/

If you inspect the table, you'll see it has

```
border-collapse: seperate;
border-spacing: 0;
```

For whatever reason, these are required to get the curved edges.
Unfortunately, this also results in each cell having a border on it's inside walls, 
and when the cells collapse together, it seems as if the inside walls all have double thick border.

Is there any way to fix this with pure CSS or HTML?

Comment: if you just want outside border, put the table in a div, give the div the border, and you are good to go.

Comment: You should wrap your table in a `div`, style the `border-radius` for the div and set `border-collapse:collapse` for the table, it saves you much CSS code, check this http://jsfiddle.net/LwT7k/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CSS like below.

```
table {
   border-spacing: 0;
 }
th, td {
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #000;
padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
border-radius: 0 0 0 0.6em;    
}
tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
border-radius: 0 0 0.6em 0;
}
tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
border-radius: 0.6em 0 0 0;
border-top:1px solid #000;
}
tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
border-radius: 0 0.6em 0 0;
border-top:1px solid #000;
}
tbody tr td:last-child{
border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/LwT7k/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/LwT7k/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
td {
    border-bottom:0px solid #000;
}
tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
td:first-child {
    border-right:0px solid #000;
    border-right:0px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

tr td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LwT7k/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set cellpadding and cellspacing on your table tag:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Hope it helps.